# Spring profile configuration based on multiple directories

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

My spring boot application.properties need to be setup for different environments like dev, test, uat and prod. The current project setup loads properties from application.properties (classpath:resources) and config.properties (this one having overrides for connections in dev, test, prod).
We have a bunch of other .properties file and jks files per environment.
I want to split the application.properties per env as such:

```
classpath: 
resources/default/* (loads each property everytime)
resources/local/* (only overrides for local + jks file for this env)
resources/dev/* (only overrides for local + jks file for this env)
resources/test/* (only overrides for local + jks file for this env)
resources/prod/* (only overrides for local + jks file for this env)
```

I am using @configurationproperties and @value to bind values. I can pass spring.profiles.active from manifests. How can I achieve this  ?

Comment: Use externalized configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set some System properties for that ( normally done in main, right before the `SpringApplication.run(UserApiApplication.class, args);`

The properties are the following. 
`System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "classpath:/config/dev/");`

note resources folder is ommited. 
Loading them is actually done with spring profiles where the profile name is the file name.

for example `config/dev/application-something.yml` is the profile something
that needs to be enabled. This is a simple guide to help you out.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles